# how to access value of variable in below scenario

Tags: python, pandas

I am having below scenario in python code:

`valuesarray = ['None','FULL']`  --> values of the column 'GLASS' of dataframe df

`keysarray = ['GLASS','SUBJECT']`

I have value 'GLASS' coming from some upper code. I am assigning it to keyvalue

`keyvalue = keysarray[0]`

I am trying to get all the records for glass matching None and Full from the dataframe.

`df= df[df.keyvalue.isin(valuesarray)]`

But, getting error --> keyvalue is not a column for the dataframe.
How to access value of variable keyvalue in this scenario? any idea?

Comment: can you post the sample data and expected output

Comment: What are the columns in your dataframe?